# ¿Cómo hacer un slider con id?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hice un slider con javascript y html, pero el problema es que mi página está hecha en php, y no es un solo slider sino varios; al momento en que termina de pasar la última imagen, en vez de empezar en la primera, otra vez se va al siguiente slider, y lo que quiero hacer es darle el id de la publicación para que al terminar de mostrar la última imagen, vuelva a la primera imagen, pero no sé cómo pasar el id de la publicación que lo obtengo con código php y mysql a javascript.

Este es el código html y javascript:

```
<div class="slideshow-container" id="ima-<?php echo $fila['id'];?>">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
  <img src="<?php echo $fila['Producto'];?> "  style="width:100%">
  
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
  <img src="<?php echo $fila['Producto2'];?> "  style="width:100%">
  
</div>



<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">
  
  <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrow-left-circle-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
             <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-4.5.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H5.707l2.147-2.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L5.707 8.5H11.5z"/>
            </svg>

</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">
  

  <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-11.5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h5.793L8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8.5H4.5z"/>
            </svg>


</a>


</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  
</div>



<script>

  




var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

 
</script>
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Y todabia tienes el mismo ploblema o no?

Comment: Si sigues con el mismo problema esto puede servirte: https://www.sololearn.com/learn/PHP/1839/

Answer (score 0):

Y que tal si recurres a un array.

```
const b=<?php echo $len; ?>;
var a=[b];

for (var i=0;i<b;i++)
a[i]=<?php echo $id[i]; ?>;

var x=0;
var img=document.getElementById("imagenes");

function click(){
img.src=a[x];
x++;
if(x==b)x=0;
}
```

Porfavor si te sirvió envíame una respuesta que no se mucho php.